# Recommendations of static site generator which accepts Markdown documents?

Tags: generator, markdown, static-site

I'm looking for static site generator which accepts Markdown documents as input source code.
I used `Markdoc`, but it looks abandoned. And it doesn't copy static file in source document folder. So I'm installing `docpad` now. Anyway I want to try other implementations. Can you recommend some nice implementation like that site generator?

Answer (score 34):

http://staticsitegenerators.net is a crowd-sourced definitive listing of all the static site generators, their github stars, their website, their language, created and updated dates, etc.

+1 for [DocPad](http://docpad.org), I've found Jekyll to be quite crippling with it's lack of extensibility (not enough markups supported, difficult to filter documents in content listings based on certain criteria, hard to write extensions, etc...)

Answer (score 8):

You can also take a look at [nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/), which is Ruby based and actively being developed, too.

Comment: YES for Nanoc - it's solid, flexible and powerful. I've used it on a few sites

Answer (score 7):

[Cabin](http://www.cabinjs.com/) is a node.js static site generator powered by Grunt. It currently has three beautiful blogging themes available out of the box. [Getting started](http://www.cabinjs.com/#getting-started) takes like 45 seconds. Here are the available themes, with links to installing each:

[image: Candy Theme]

[image: Blok Theme]

[image: Canvas Theme]

Comment: links are not working anymore

Answer (score 6):

[Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) is quite mature and actively being developped.

Comment: Actually I decided to make my own implementation with `markdown` program. It was easier than configuring Jekyll to work.

Answer (score 3):

[Poole](https://hg.sr.ht/~obensonne/poole) is another one. Conceptually it's something in between plain Markdown to HTML conversion and more sophisticated site generators like [Hyde](http://ringce.com/hyde).

Poole uses *one* global HTML skeleton file to inject the HTML versions of Markdown source pages into. Poole has basic support for generating content by embedding Python code in page source files. This is a dirty merge of content and logic but a pragmatic solution to get things done fast for simple sites. No need to learn a template or preprocessing engine.

Poole may be a good choice if you are familiar with Markdown and Python and if you want to build a rather simple site with only a spot of generated content.

*Disclaimer: I'm the developer of Poole.*

Comment: Poole has now "Last updated  2015-07-13".

Comment: Found some time to maintain it again. Project is now at https://hg.sr.ht/~obensonne/poole.

Answer (score 2):

I recently moved my [blog](http://blog.sanjeevonline.com) from googlesites to node based [Wintersmith](http://wintersmith.io/). I am fairly impressed with the flexibility and markdown support it provides. Also there are several templates and open source referral websites available on their git repository.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a mac, I recommend Hammer (http://hammerformac.com/). Supports Markdown and also SASS (with Bourbon), CoffeeScript and HAML.